# issue in create table using another table in hive

Tags: hadoop, memory, hive

In hive there is a test table. table data have multiple small files so I want create another table using that test table so the newly created table will have less partitions and query will be fast. But I creating new table it gives me error.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_merge
     STORED AS parquet
AS
  SELECT * FROM test;
```

Error

```
ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 3 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20180108060101_7bca2cc8-e19b-4e6d-aa00-362039526523); Time taken: 366.845 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 3 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask (state=08S01,code=3)
```

It is working fine with less data. example

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_merge
     STORED AS parquet
AS
  SELECT * FROM test limit 100000;
```

It may be memory issues, I don't know. Please help

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to write parquet format files, spark would catch a batch of rows into data block called "Row Group" before flush them to disk. So usually it requires more memory than row oriented formats. Try to increase "spark.executor.memory" or decrease "parquet.block.size", this may help

Comment: Where can I give the property. As don't have spark job. I am using beeline to execute the query. How I can increase the spark.executor.memory in beeline editor

Comment: inside hive-site.xml file you can increase the spark.executor.memory value..or you can set these value while executing the hive query like SET parquet.block.size=134217728;

Comment: Thanks. But I change the hive-site.xml. Is there any way that I can give this property to specific hive job. Like we can give executor memory to spark job in spark-submit command.

Comment: for changing **spark.executor.memory** you have to change in  `spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`

Comment: This may help you. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started